# HTML download link wont download file from server in Visual Studio 19

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor, visual-studio-2019

I'm having an issue with my cshtml code in vs2019. I need to be able to fetch a file from a server and be able to download it via download link with HMTL5. If i use the code outside of vs2019 it works but within vs2019 it doesn't work; any ideas? I've already check privileges and such and non of that seems to be an issue.

This is the cshtml view code from my controller.

```
@{
     ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

 <h2>Index</h2>
 <h1>
   <a 
     href="\\someserver\somefolder\anotherfolder\yetanotherfolder\test.txt" 
    download> 
     Test </a>
 </h1>
```

Comment: Please provide some code so we can help you. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Add the the view code.